# Javascript Function in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I am developing an Quiz Application in MVC 5. I have added two tables in database. One for marks and other for Questions and Answers. I have entered data in database for question, answers and have entered bool value as true or false for correct answer and vice versa. I am able to view Question and Answers from database.But I got stuck whenever user checks the checkboxes i want to give him points based on correct or wrong answer. I am not able to write javascript function in order to check whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Javascript:

```
function scorecheck(id) {

    if (document.getElementById(id).checked) {
        document.getElementById(id).value = "false";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(id).value = "true";
    }
}
```

Razor view:

```
   @using(Html.BeginForm("Score", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
   {
   foreach (var item in Model) {

   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Question)

   @Html.CheckBox("ans1", new { onchange = "scorecheck()" })
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ans1)<br />

 @Html.CheckBox("ans2", new { onchange = "scorecheck()" })
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ans2)<br />

 @Html.CheckBox("ans3", new { onchange = "scorecheck()" })
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ans3)<br />

 @Html.CheckBox("ans4", new { onchange = "scorecheck()" })
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ans4)<br />
  }

<input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
   }
```

Also I have written logic for giving points for correct and wrong answer but it is not working.

C#:

```
int s = 0;
        string ans1 = c["ans1"];
        if (ans1 == "true")
        {
            s = s + 20;
        }
        string ans2 = c["ans2"];
        if (ans2 == "false")
        {
            s = s - 20;
        }
        string ans3 = c["ans3"];
        if (ans3 == "false")
        {
            s = s - 20;
        }
        string ans4 = c["ans4"];
        if (ans4 == "false")
        {
            s = s - 20;
        }
```

Comment: you can use jquery  like $("#checkkBoxId").attr("checked")

Comment: Do you want to have points calculated immediately after clicking any checkbox or you want to calculate the sum after for is posted?

Comment: I have to calculate Score after submitting.

Comment: Have you tried the following: `if(document.getElementById('ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4').checked)`? Considering that 'ans1' for example is the id of the property.

Comment: I used :  <input id="@(item.ans1)" type="checkbox" name="ans1" value="@item.ans1" onchange="scorecheck('@(item.ans1)')" />  for getting id from checkboxes. Then I am using :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can check the value of checkbox on click:

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="yourvalue" onclick="MyFunc(this)">
```

and the javascript function:

```
function MyFunc(control)
{
  if(control.checked==true)
   //your logic
}
```

Comment: I am using an razor view

Answer (score 0):

I have used following to get id from checkboxes:

```
`<input id="@(item.ans1)" type="checkbox" name="ans1" value="@item.ans1" onchange="scorecheck('@(item.ans1)')" /> `
```

Then I am using Javascript Function to check if its value is true or false like this:

`if (document.getElementById(id).checked) {
            document.getElementById(id).value = "True";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(id).value = "False";
        }`